# Change color of the overflow button on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to change the color of the overflow button(3 vertical dots) on the action bar?
If so, how do we do that? I didn't find any style for overflow button.

Thanks

Comment: Yes possible, `<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>` add it to your style.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can change the image used for it using the following style declaration.

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

And if you're using ActionBarSherlock, here's how to do it

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Comment: For some reason that did not work for me with target sdk 15, running on a Galaxy Nexus (JellyBean).  The 3-dot menu button remains the same.

Comment: To retain the default overflow button settings (e.g. height/width, on-touch overlay graphic) and change only the icon image, add the parent to the custom overflow style: `parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow"`

Comment: So there's no way to change the color of the "..." icon without adding an entirely new image?

Comment: @VinceFior  did you figure out how to change the color besides creating a whole new image?  This seems really really odd to me..

Comment: @reidisaki No, I ended up making a new image, I'm afraid. It wasn't really that bad, but I agree it seems silly.

Comment: I also did.. I just used their dark/light versions of the ic_overflow.png

Comment: How could tf can I do this programmatically?

Comment: It picks color from textColorPrimary, so rather than writing multiple lines this single line `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>` will fix your problem. 
Only a small problem is that this color will be apply to the textcolor of your overflow menu also, and lots of other places of-course.

Comment: If you don't want to change the image take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932669/how-do-i-change-the-action-bar-overflow-button-color

Answer (score 41):

Some of these answers are serious overkill and some give limited results.  The answer is much simpler.  You can set it to whatever color you want, any time. 
 Here:

```
toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(colorInt, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Brilliant! After several hours of search it works. Instead of `colorInt` use `ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray)`.

Comment: colorInt just refers to any color referenced by its integer value

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme#comment57980762_27517878) is the correct way to do it. It changes the colour of the back button too.

Comment: I used `setTint` in the following manner, now that `setColorFilter` is deprecated: `.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))`

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is `toolbar`? I only have an `ActionBar`.

Comment: ```Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);``` You can use a Toolbar in xml for the ActionBar by using the method ```setSupportActionBar(toolbar);```

Comment: For ```colorInt``` I used ```getResources().getColor(R.color.color)```

Comment: This only works if you replace the default ActionBar with a Toolbar.

Answer (score 20):

[XGouchet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427992/649181) is great, but just wanted to add that if you inherit from an existing style you'll get the standard padding, selected state, etc.

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/title_moreicon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: parent="android:Widget.ActionButton.Overflow"

Comment: for me : parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow"

Answer (score 11):

Other programmatically option:

```
        Drawable drawable = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), getResources().getColor(R.color.thecolor));
            toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using AppCompat , you could derive a new custom style with the attribute `android:textColorSecondary`set to the required color, and use it as the theme for your toolbar.
[Android: Changing the Toolbar’s text color and overflow icon color](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/)

Comment: This is in my eyes the actual way to go if you want to change the dot color without too much fuss!

Answer (score 3):

Putting images is not a great idea, because if you can change it by changing colors only then no need to use an extra image.
The menu dots picks color from textColorPrimary, so rather than writing multiple lines this single line 
`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>` will fix your problem. 
Only a small problem is that this color will be apply to the textcolor of your overflow menu also, and lots of other places of-course :)

Comment: It's android:textColorSecondary.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest Toolbar, you have to put the statement in styles.xml, as shown in the code below:

```
<style name="AppToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change overflow icon color to color of your choice..... User them

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/actionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>
 <style name="actionButtonOverflow"   parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="OverflowMenuButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="android:src">@drawable/quantum_ic_more_vert_white_24</item>
</style>
```

Note that this is different from XGouchet's answer by removing android namespace. XGouchet's answer only works for Lollipop and higher devices while mine works for all API 7+ devices.

ref: [Custom AppCompat Theme not changing Overflow icon on older devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108027/custom-appcompat-theme-not-changing-overflow-icon-on-older-devices)

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in your choosen style in style.xma file

`<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>`

its working fine.
if you use

`<item name="textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>`

then  your other items like drawer navigation menu icons color and radio button will be affected

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu); // dashboard is xml file name
        Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.lan).getIcon();
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It's working for me and I found it from  [here](https://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-change-color-of-menu-item-icon-in-android.916282/)

Comment: Isn't that only for menu items ?

Answer (score 0):

For Overflow icon color change, you can just add

```
toolbar.setOverflowicon(getDrawable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the 3 dots icon white instead of black you can simply change the theme of the toolbar to this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     ...
     android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
 />
```

full reference here:
   [medium.com/the-curious-case-of-the-overflow-icon-color](https://medium.com/@mbonnin/the-curious-case-of-the-overflow-icon-color-39d8c3497ccc#0024)

Comment: Changing the theme also change the whole application appearance that is not what people want.

Answer (score 0):

Material3 toolbar setup:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/material3_primary</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/back_arrow</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution in Kotlin:

```
    val toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar? = findViewById(R.id.tbMenu)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar?.overflowIcon?.setTint(getColor(R.color.white))
```