# Change OverflowButton of ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Do we have any way to change the icon/background of this button in code, I found one way to change it in XML in this [Change color of the overflow button on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660/change-color-of-the-overflow-button-on-actionbar) , but I want to change it dynamically from my code.