# How to change the color of the Overflow Button Icon on the ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

trying to change the color of the three dots for the android overflow button. I looked online for a solution and couldn't seem to find a clear answer. I looked at this stackOverflow post: [Change color of the overflow button on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660/change-color-of-the-overflow-button-on-actionbar) and the solution didn't work. I didn't really see the logic going in though, and copying and pasting the solution into my code didn't seem like the most sure fire route. If anyone has any tips, or would be willing to explain solution from the previous post on the same question, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us where in the previous post you don't understand?

Comment: well, it seems like the answer to that post claims that all you have to do is copy and paste the code that it gives into 'styles'. That didn't work. Also, I don't even see how it works, as it doesn't access any android specific variables related to the overflow button.

Comment: That post is right. I have used the exact same technique to replace the overflow icon. This technique is call style and theme. When you do custom view, the three argument constructor would use the values set in style and theme to get the custom overflow icon image.

Comment: i see, but you can't change the color of the current icon correct?

Comment: You can change the color of the current icon by supplying a different image, but I am not sure if you can do it via code as i never tried it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color of the overflow button on ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660/change-color-of-the-overflow-button-on-actionbar)