# How to change color of the back arrow in the new material theme?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, colors, android-styles

I've updated my SDK to API 21 and now the back/up icon is a black arrow pointing to the left.

[image: Black back arrow]

I would like it to be grey. How can I do that?

In the Play Store, for example, the arrow is white.

I've done this to set some styles. I have used `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` for `homeAsUpIndicator`. That drawable is transparent (only alpha) but the arrow is displayed in black. I wonder if I can set the color like I do in the `DrawerArrowStyle`. Or if the only solution is to create my `@drawable/grey_arrow` and use it for `homeAsUpIndicator`.

```xml
<!-- Base application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator" tools:ignore="NewApi">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar style -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">

    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for the navigation drawer icon -->
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

My solution so far has been to take the `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`, which seems to be white, and paint it in the color I desire using a photo editor. It works, although I would prefer to use `@color/actionbar_text` like in `DrawerArrowStyle`.

Comment: None of the XML-based answers so far have solved this issue for me, but I have successfully used your `homeAsUpIndicator` / `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` code to make the back arrow white. I prefer this than hacking into the Java.

Comment: Old but still. Are (were) you using ActionBar or the new Toolbar?

Comment: The default one is supposed to be a bit gray, by using android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar" inside the Toolbar XML tag. Its color is #737373

Answer (score 371, accepted):

You can achieve it through code. Obtain the back arrow drawable, modify its color with a filter, and set it as back button.

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

**Revision 1:**

Starting from API 23 (Marshmallow) the drawable resource `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` is changed to `abc_ic_ab_back_material`.

EDIT:

You can use this code to achieve the results you want:

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_gray_15), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: problem with this solution is it paints all your other back arrows, if you only want to change one and leave the rest white

Comment: cant find `R.color.grey` what is the color?

Comment: @ssh you have to define the a string attribute in your colors.xml file(in res/values) with the name as grey as follows `<color name="grey">#808080</color>`

Comment: @Carles, it coloured the back arrow white alright. But now it doesn't function properly! It doesn't go back to the previous activity!

Comment: It works. Please note you should use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha)` because `getResources.getDrawable(int)` is deprecated

Comment: It's better to change the color of arrow rather than using images. The attribute `colorControlNormal` decides the color of arrow. So change this attribute in your toolbar custom theme and enjoy :)

Comment: for problem where it changes all back arrow color in application you can use mutate()..
upArrow.mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: Another possible solution would be for you to get that resource yourself and put it on your drawable folders :)

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor() should also be used instead of getResources().getColor()

Comment: Note that abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha changed to abc_ic_ab_back_material in the 23.2.0 support library

Comment: In my case, the drawable resource is private and I can't use it, so I solved it using this another solution that worked for me (using styles only): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28631979/2969811

Comment: Note that, if you are using toolbar with theme ".NoActionBar", then getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow); won't work. 
Use toolbar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow); then

Comment: this will not work when you upgrade support design version

Comment: Though this solution works, Lint will show a warning, so I applied a solution with `getNavigationIcon()` here.

Comment: Future readers, make sure you do `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` before doing `toolbar?.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)`

Answer (score 213):

Looking at the `Toolbar` and `TintManager` source, `drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` is tinted with the value of the style attribute `colorControlNormal`.

I did try setting this in my project (with `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>` in my theme), but it's still black for me.

**Update**:

Found it. You need to set the `actionBarTheme` attribute (**not** `actionBarStyle`) with `colorControlNormal`.

Eg:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">        
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyApp.ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <!-- color for widget theming, eg EditText. Doesn't effect ActionBar. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
    <!-- The animated arrow style -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">       
    <!-- THIS is where you can color the arrow! -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>      
    <!-- style for actionBar title -->  
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <!-- style for actionBar subtitle -->  
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubtitleText</item>

    <!-- 
    the actionBarTheme doesn't use the colorControlNormal attribute
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
     -->
</style>
```

Comment: I need to add also  <item name="android:colorControlNormal">...</item> with the android: prefix

Comment: Unfortunately this is a level 21 API and if you want to support anything below it won't work.

Comment: Worked, but with a tweak. Instead of using `colorControlNormal` as rockgecko suggested I threw it inside `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">` which is then applied per activity.

Comment: If your parent theme derives from one of the "NoActionBar" themes, then setting `colorControlNormal` on the root theme rather than in the `actionBarTheme` is the route to go.

Answer (score 127):

Tried all suggestions above. The only way that I managed to change the color of navigation icon default Back button arrow in my toolbar is to set colorControlNormal in base theme like this. Probably due to the fact that the parent is using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> 
  //the rest of your codes...
</style>
```

Comment: remember that colorControlNormal requires API 21

Comment: @AdnanAli if you're using AppCompat it'll work on < API 21 as well. Clearly, AppCompat _is_ being used here because `colorControlNormal` is _not_ prefixed with `android:`.

Comment: But this changes the tint off all other widgets as well.. any way not to affect other widgets such as checkbox and radio buttons?

Comment: Changing theme to Xxx.NoActionBar causes NPE on "getSupportActionBar".

Comment: @Henry NoActionBar theme won't provide default action bar. So you need to setup your own toolbar by like so `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` where toolbar is the one you setup in xml.

Answer (score 70):

Need to add a single attribute to your toolbar theme -

```
<style name="toolbar_theme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/arrow_color</item>
</style>
```

Apply this toolbar_theme to your toolbar.

**OR**

you can directly apply to your theme -

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/arrow_color</item> 
  //your code ....
</style>
```

Answer (score 46):

Just add

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

to your current app theme.

Comment: This is changing the android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox color also

Answer (score 37):

if use `Toolbar`,you can try this

```
Drawable drawable = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(appCompatActivity, colorId), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Note that you might need to call this before attempting to call getNavigationIcon(): getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 34):

As said on most of the previous comments, the solution is to add

`<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>` 
to your app theme. 
But confirm that you don´t have another theme defined in your Toolbar element on your layout.

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer by Carles is the correct answer, but few of the methods like ***getDrawable(), getColor() got deprecated at the time I am writing this answer***. So the updated answer would be

```
Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

---

Following some other stackoverflow queries I found that calling ***ContextCompat.getDrawable()*** is similar to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

---

And **ContextCompat.getColor()** is similar to

```
public static final int getColor(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompatApi23.getColor(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

***[Link 1: ContextCompat.getDrawable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)***

***[Link 2: ContextCompat.getColor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23)***

Comment: It should be `abc_ic_ab_back_material`, instead of `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that works pre Lollipop.  Set the "colorControlNormal" within the "actionBarWidgetTheme" to change the homeAsUpIndicator color.  Modifying rockgecko's answer from above to look like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">        
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyApp.ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <!-- color for widget theming, eg EditText. Doesn't effect ActionBar. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
    <!-- The animated arrow style -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <!-- The style for the widgets on the ActionBar. -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/WidgetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="WidgetStyle" parent="style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

On compileSdkVersoin 25, you could do this:

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Change Menu Nav Icon Color

[image: Final convert Menu Icon Color]

In style.xml :

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>







In Mainfests.xml :

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"></activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use below method:

```
private Drawable getColoredArrow() {
    Drawable arrowDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(arrowDrawable);

    if (arrowDrawable != null && wrapped != null) {
        // This should avoid tinting all the arrows
        arrowDrawable.mutate();
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, Color.GRAY);
    }

    return wrapped;
}
```

Now you can set the drawable with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getColoredArrow());
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution is very simple

Just put following line into your style named as **AppTheme**

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

Now your whole xml code will look like shown below (default style).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#0F0F0F</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#EEEEF0</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that might work for you is to not declare your toolbar as the app's action bar ( by `setActionBar` or `setSupportActionBar` ) and set the back icon in your onActivityCreated using the code mentioned in another answer on this page

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow);
```

Now, you will not get the `onOptionItemSelected` callback when you press the back button. However, you can register for that using `setNavigationOnClickListener`. This is what i do:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().onBackPressed(); //or whatever you used to do on your onOptionItemSelected's android.R.id.home callback
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if it will work if you work with menu items.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it in Material Components:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

Add the below attributes to your theme.

To change toolbar/actionbar back arrow above api 21

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_drawable_icon</item>
```

To change toolbar/actionbar back arrow below api 21

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_drawable_icon</item>
```

To change action mode back arrow

```
<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/your_drawable_icon</item>
```

To remove toolbar/actionbar shadow

```
<item name="android:elevation" tools:targetApi="lollipop">0dp</item>
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
<!--backward compatibility-->
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

To change actionbar overflow drawable

```
<!--under theme-->
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MenuOverflowStyle</item>

<style name="MenuOverflowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
<item name="srcCompat">@drawable/ic_menu_overflow</item>
```

Note : 'srcCompat' is used instead of 'android:src' because of vector drawable support for api below 21

Answer (score 3):

We were running into the same problem and all we wanted was to set the

**app:collapseIcon**

attribute in the toolbar in the end, which we did not find since it is not very well documented :)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight"
         app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapseBackIcon" />
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
public void enableActionBarHomeButton(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, int colorId){

    final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(appCompatActivity, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(appCompatActivity, colorId), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

function call:

```
enableActionBarHomeButton(this, R.color.white);
```

Comment: Setting the {@link #DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP} display option will automatically enable the home button.

Answer (score 3):

I just changed the toolbar theme to be @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light

and the arrow became dark gray

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and best) way to change the color of the back/up-arrow. Best part is
that there are **no side-effects** (unlike the other answers)!

- Create a style with parent `Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle`, define the `color` and any other attributes you'd like.
- Set the style on the `drawerArrowStyle` attribute in the apps Theme.

**Create style:**

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <!--        Set that the nav buttons will animate-->
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <!--        Set the color of the up arrow / hamburger button-->
    <item name="color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Set the style in App Theme:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!--  Change global up-arrow color with no side-effects    -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

To change the `ToolBar` text color (and other attributes), create this `style`:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> <!-- colorControlNormal is Probably not necessary    -->
</style>
```

Then set that style on the AppTheme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.MyProduceApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!--  Style the toolbar (mostly the color of the text) -->
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
    <!--  Change color of up-arrow    -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the navigation icon programmatically like this:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getColoredArrow()); 

private Drawable getColoredArrow() {
        Drawable arrowDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(arrowDrawable);

        if (arrowDrawable != null && wrapped != null) {
            // This should avoid tinting all the arrows
            arrowDrawable.mutate();
                DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrapped, ColorStateList.valueOf(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)));
            }
        }

        return wrapped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun setToolbarNavigationIconColor(context: Context, toolbar: Toolbar?, color: Int) {
    val drawableBack = toolbar?.navigationIcon
    drawableBack?.let {
        val drawableWrap = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawableBack).mutate()
        DrawableCompat.setTint(
            drawableWrap, ContextCompat.getColor(context, white)
        )
        toolbar.navigationIcon = drawableWrap
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw all soluation but didn't fix the problem , If you need fix the problem just add in XMl file this code if you but dark make it light

```
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `android:homeAsUpIndicator` and `homeAsUpIndicator` from your theme and it will be fine. The `color` attribute in your `DrawerArrowStyle` style must be enough.

Comment: I already tried that and the arrow is black. Note this arrow is not the same arrow you see when you open the drawer (that arrow IS affected by the `color` attribute). The drawer arrow is a bit bigger.

Comment: So, it seems you'll have to provide your own drawable resource. You can generate it using this tool: http://shreyasachar.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score -4):

Unless there's a better solution...

What I did is to take the `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` images, which seem to be white, and paint them in the color I desire using a photo editor.