# Android Searchview back button color change

Tags: android, searchview

How to change the color of black arrow(Back button) in searchview
I have tried by customizing with below code

```
    ImageView backid = (ImageView) searchViewAndroidActionBar.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    backid.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(Shopping_CategoriesCommon.this, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    backid.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme

Answer (score 16):

Add this attribute to your toolbar in xml file
**app:collapseIcon**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight"
     app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapseBackIcon" />
```

Answer (score 12):

After a day search i resolved it by adding `app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_arrow"` to the custom toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_arrow"/>
```

Comment: Can we set collpaseIcon on runtime?

Answer (score 4):

I could change the color using Reflection.

```
try {
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    Field mCollapseIcon = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapseIcon");
    mCollapseIcon.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drw = (Drawable) mCollapseIcon.get(toolbar);
    drw.setTint(color);
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```