# Android: I'm using AppCompatv7 library, but can't access any of its icons?

Tags: android, resources, icons, android-appcompat

So I'm having trouble accessing the appcompat icons in the library and I dunno why.

```
// build.gradle
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`
```

I'm trying to use this icon: `@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha`

```
// styles.xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha</item>
</style>
```

But I get this error: `Error:(12, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'homeAsUpIndicator' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha').`

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support library v7:23.2.0 now supports Vector Drawable.

This way, a lot of drawable become useless or obsolete and where removed.

I think that `abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha` was replaced by `abc_ic_clear_material` which uses vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    <path
            android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5,12,10.59,6.41,5,5,6.41,10.59,12,5,17.59,6.41,19,12,13.41,17.59,19,19,17.59,13.41,12z"
            android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
</vector>
```

As you can see, the new icon uses vector and colorControlNormal.

You may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653131/back-arrow-and-overflow-icons-wrong-color-in-pre-lollipop-devices-after-updating/35654779#35654779) to check how to enable Vector and change the color of the icons.

Answer (score 0):

For newest versions you can found **abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha** and a lot of other icons doing this:

> android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_material