# Android toolbar white vs black

Tags: android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/purple2"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />
```

On my **nexus 6**, the back button is white, the 3 dot menu is white and the title is white. On an emulator I run, **API level 14** the title is white but the back arrow and dot menu are black. How come?

Comment: In which way is this related to **CSS**? You probably have a different theme for those API levels.

Comment: Which design support library are you using? Which version?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0' compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix similar issue by checking solution below. I posted this same solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35654779/4860513).

I found that AppCompat theme is using following resource for overflow button (3 dots): `abc_ic_menu_overflow_material.xml`

Content of this resource is:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    ...
</vector>
```

So, as you can see, it is using colorControlNormal and vectorDrawables

**HOW TO FIX**

According to Library V23.2.0 Release notes ([LINK HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)), we have to update build.gradle to add support to Vector:

**build.gradle**

Add following lines to your build gradle

Gradle 2.0 (I did not tested):

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

Gradle 1.5 (I'm using this.. it works):

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        generatedDensities = []  
    }  

    aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
    }  
}
```

**Fix your theme**

Maybe, this step is not needed (because maybe, your parent theme already set the colors to white).

But if those buttons remains black, you must add ColorControlNormal to your theme:

**ToolbarLayout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyToolBarStyle"
    ...  />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</styel>
```

This was how I fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.myapp.app"
>     minSdkVersion 10
>     targetSdkVersion 22
>     multiDexEnabled true
>     versionCode 25
>     versionName "1.24"
>     generatedDensities = []
> }
> // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
> // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
> aaptOptions {
>     additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
> }
> ```

This solved situation for my 2 devices, not sure if now in all devices same story.