# How to set Toolbar background color in an activity to a color inside colors.xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have a color in my `colors.xml` file which I need to use for `toolbar` color

```
<resources>
    <color name="MAIN_A">#f16264</color>
</resources>
```

Now I need to use `MAIN_A` as a color for `toolbar`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this code

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
```

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated.

Comment: @CoolMind Not true. It is deprecated in other classes but not in ActionBar.class

Comment: @GabrielBB, hmm, maybe you are right, but `ActionBar` itself is deprecated and here `getSupportActionBar()` is used.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code for Kotlin

```
supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating new layout resource toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/MAIN_A" />
```

And then include it in your activity layout like this:

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Then you need to set this toolbar in your activity onCreate method:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        // set toolbar object as actionbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

After that you can access your new action bar from getSupportActionBar() method. Tell me if it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Try it like that:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_A)));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, **ActionBar** is depricated, use **Toolbar** (android.widget.Toolbar) instead.
If this is not possible, try the support of ActionBar as follows :

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_A)));
```

For the toolbar, it's :

```
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.MAIN_A)
```

Comment: how do I change the color bacground for Toolbar??

Comment: @user5148540
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.MAIN_A)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a custom **toolbar** considering the API 23+.

1 - `Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.yourtoolbarId);`

2 - `mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#004D40"));`

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar **background**, **text**, **arrow** and three-dots popup **menu color**.

1) Background:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.toolbar_color));
```

or (requires API 16):

```
toolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.toolbar_color)));
```

2) Title:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray);
```

3) Arrow:

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

4) Popup menu three-dots icon (right icon):

```
toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26837072/2914140 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908890/2914140.

All in one (in Kotlin):

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue))
val toolbarTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray)
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(toolbarTextColor)
toolbar.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(toolbarTextColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
toolbar.overflowIcon?.setColorFilter(toolbarTextColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question you have not used SupportActionBar so you can do like as below:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_A)));
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  // required to force redraw, without, gray color
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Actual credit goes to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/2715073) of SO.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the "best method" but i just tried this and it works fine, even if it should be considered a temporary measure until someone finds a better one, and it works PRE- API23...
You can make a new xml layout for each separate use of the toolbar, for example toolbar1.xml, toolbar2.xml etc. Then in the activity code add this to onCreate:

for toolbar1:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new colorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAdmin))); 

LayoutInflater inflater_admin = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

@SuppressLint("InflateParams") View action_bar_view_admin = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater_admin).inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar_admin, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(action_bar_view_admin);
```

---

for toolbar2:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new colorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOwner))); 

LayoutInflater inflater_owner = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

@SuppressLint("InflateParams") View action_bar_view_owner = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater_owner).inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar_owner, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(action_bar_view_owner);
```

---

etc...

Hope this helps someone!