# Change Toolbar overflow icon color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-toolbar

I have an `android.support.v7.widget` Toolbar in my Android app. The background color of this is bright orange and the best looking color on top of this would be white instead of black.

I have the default color on black and not white. Since it would conflict with other stuff, that is almost impossible to override. **I cannot change the primary text color to white!**

I've managed to change the title color. 
**What I'm looking for right now is how I can change the action button color as well (to white).**

[image]

My code:

Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".UI.activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/r2_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/primary_text_material_light"
    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/primary_text_material_light"
    android:theme="@style/R2Theme.Toolbar"/>

<fragment android:name="com.r2retail.r2retailapp.UI.fragments.SetupFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:title="About"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

<style name="R2Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">=
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/primary_text_material_light</item>
</style>

<style name="R2Theme.Toolbar" parent="R2Theme">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/primary_text_material_light</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Is there is not way to customize the ic_menu color, directly from it's file like changing `fillColor` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of the overflow button on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660/change-color-of-the-overflow-button-on-actionbar)

Comment: Note to reviewers: Toolbar and the action bar are two different widgets.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">#62ff00</item>
</style>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @azizbekian thanks, it worked but what if i want to change the back arrow(in the child activity) color too?

Comment: @Shiva welcome. Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme)?

Comment: @azizbekian, yeah after that only i found that link and yup it worked but failed to update here, thanks a lot

Comment: Works very well with the new BottomAppBar as well. Have an upvote.

Comment: Does not work if i use parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and apply the AppTheme to whole application.

Comment: Not working for me either. I have a NoActionBar theme applied to the activity in the manifest, but the rest is identical to above.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to replace icon itself.

**1st**

Go to **values/styles** and in your `styles.xml` file add:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <!--Here you need to put name of drawable you will create during the next step-->
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_white_icon</item> 
</style>
```

**2nd**

Then go to **drawable** folder. Right mouse click -> new -> vector asset.
Then press on **Icon** image and choose from suggested icon named **ic_more_vert_black_24dp**.

Customize it -> press next -> finish.

Then open newly created icon file. Code looks like this.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF" <!-- Here u can change color-->
        android:pathData="M12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,10c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,16c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Change `fillColor` attribute to the color you need. Put this file to the styles how described in 1st step.

Voila! Color of our *three dots* changed not depending on base app styles (result for #FF2012 color).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way, in code instead of XML:

```
public static boolean colorizeToolbarOverflowButton(@NonNull Toolbar toolbar, @ColorInt int color) {
    final Drawable overflowIcon = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if (overflowIcon == null)
        return false;
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getTintedDrawable(toolbar.getContext(), overflowIcon, toolbarIconsColor));
    return true;
}

public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Drawable inputDrawable, @ColorInt int color) {
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(inputDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrapDrawable, Mode.SRC_IN);
    return wrapDrawable;
}
```

The function will return true if succeeded to colorize the overflow icon.

And another alternative, in case you prefer not to use a tinted drawable:

```
public static boolean colorizeToolbarOverflowButton(@NonNull Toolbar toolbar, @ColorInt Integer color) {
    final Drawable overflowIcon = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if (overflowIcon == null)
        return false;
    final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = toolbarIconsColor == null ? null : new PorterDuffColorFilter(toolbarIconsColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    overflowIcon.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    return true;
}
```

In addition, if you wish to colorize the icons of the action items and the nav item, you can try this (based on [**here**](https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/)):

```
/**
 * Use this method to colorize toolbar icons to the desired target color
 *
 * @param toolbarView       toolbar view being colored
 * @param toolbarIconsColor the target color of toolbar icons
 */
@JvmStatic
@UiThread
fun colorizeToolbarActionItemsAndNavButton(toolbarView: Toolbar, @ColorInt toolbarIconsColor: Int?) {
    //https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/
    val colorFilter = if (toolbarIconsColor == null) null else PorterDuffColorFilter(toolbarIconsColor, Mode.MULTIPLY)
    for (i in 0 until toolbarView.childCount) {
        val v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i)
        //Step 1 : Changing the color of back button (or open drawer button).
        if (v is ImageButton) {
            //Action Bar back button
            v.drawable.mutate().colorFilter = colorFilter
        }
        if (v is ActionMenuView) {
            for (j in 0 until v.childCount) {
                //Step 2: Changing the color of any ActionMenuViews - icons that
                //are not back button, nor text, nor overflow menu icon.
                val innerView = v.getChildAt(j)
                if (innerView is ActionMenuItemView) {
                    val drawablesCount = innerView.compoundDrawables.size
                    for (k in 0 until drawablesCount) {
                        if (innerView.compoundDrawables[k] != null) {
                            innerView.post { innerView.compoundDrawables[k].mutate().colorFilter = colorFilter }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    toolbar.doOnPreDraw {
        colorizeToolbarActionItemsAndNavButton(toolbar,0xffff0000.toInt())
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For AndroidX users (really don't know if it works using old Support Library):

### TL;DR:

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Apply `MyToolbarTheme` to your `Toolbar` view.

---

### Long explanation:

`Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow` extends `Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow`. We'll be talking about the latter:

#### On the default implementation:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="RtlUnderlay.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material</item>
  ...
</style>
```

#### On API 21 implementation:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="android:src">@null</item>
  <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material</item>
</style>
```

#### On API 23 and higher implementation:

It extends `android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow`.

```
<style name="Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="src">@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_material</item>
  ...
</style>
```

We can notice that every implementation uses `@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_material`.

Inside this drawable's implementation you can see the following:

```
android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of icons (Navigation icon, menu item icons) in your toolbar, you can simply use the code below. I had saved problem and solved using this.

```
<!--Light Theme-->
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--other colors and properties-->
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>

<!-- Dark/Night theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!--other colors and properties-->
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone's looking to change it programmatically, and the following didn't work:**

```
mBinding.toolbar.overflowIcon?.setTint(Color.WHITE)
```

**OR**

```
mBinding.toolbar.overflowIcon?.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

**OR**

```
mBinding.toolbar.overflowIcon?.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(Color.WHITE, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```

**OR**

```
val overflowIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.dots_vertical_black)
overflowIcon?.setTint(Color.WHITE)
mBinding.toolbar.overflowIcon = overflowIcon
```

**TRY THIS.**

**Finally the below line worked for me (after 2 days of trial and error -_-)**

```
mBinding.toolbar.menu?.findItem(R.id.menu)?.icon?.setTint(Color.WHITE)
```